# encodeURIComponent inline on onClick

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a link on my page, that when clicked calls a method with 2 arguments.  One of these arguments may have special characters (ie ' or é etc.).  I get page errors when I try to pass such variables, so I am trying to encode them before passing them.  How can I call encodeURIComponent inline?

I am trying to do this:

```
<a  title="${facet.toolTipDisplay}" onclick="submitFacet('Company', '${encodeURIComponent(facet.javaScriptVar)}')">
```

And I seem to be getting the error:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/SearchForm.jsp(831,126) The function encodeURIComponent must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified`

DISCLAIMER: I am new to web stuff and only have access to the JSP page and not the java class where the facet.javaScriptVar is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried setting your ContentType header/meta tag to "text/html; charset=utf8"?

Comment: @Maz this is what I have now: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: @Maz SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/SearchForm.jsp(831,126) The function encodeURIComponent must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with just replacing the apostrophe with "\'" (escaped apostrophe).  When my function is called the escaped apostrophe is replaced with the apostrophe like normal.

This is what it looks like within the HTML:

```
// arguments = Company, L\'Oréal (4)
onclick="submitFacet('Company', '${fn:replace(facet.toolTipDisplay, "'", "\\'")}')"
```

Then what it looks like when the submitFacet function is called:

```
"Company", "L'Oréal (4)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are trying to use Java or JS to encode your UI component?. The easiest way I think is to use JS functions . Encoding method will depend on characters to encode, from less exclusive to most you have [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) (not suitable for uris), [encodeUri](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) and [encodeUriComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

```
<a  title="${facet.toolTipDisplay}" onclick="submitFacet('Company', 
    'encodeURIComponent(${facet.javaScriptVar})'">
```

To be more polite you could apply encoding inside your submitFacet function, just passing Company and your JSTL var.

Reading your comments I would suggest to escape va content before treat it with JS otherwise wouldn't be possible.

Try one of this 2 approaches:

```
onclick="submitFacet('<c:out value="${facet.javaScriptVar}"/>')"  

onclick="submitFacet('${fn:escapeJava(facet.javaScriptVar)}')"
```

Assuming you import [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) taglib.

Comment: the JSTL variable may contain special characters, including "'" (Apostrophe) and JS doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: Difficult to treat if they include apostrophes i would suggest you using one of these escape functions, specially the escape Java. http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29